# ls and cd give no output when used with sudo

Tags: command-line, sudo, ls

In my root user directory, `ls` outputs this:

```
Desktop    Downloads         Music     Public     Videos
Documents  examples.desktop  Pictures  Templates
```

However, `sudo -i ls` does not give any output whatsoever.

`cd Downloads` works as usual. `sudo -i cd Downloads` outputs "No such file or directory." What's happening? Shouldn't `sudo -i [command]` work the same as any command by itself?

Answer (score 1):

The `-i` option causes sudo to run the command in the shell specified by the target user's (in this case, root's) login shell, as you can confirm for example by running

```
$ sudo -i sh -c 'echo $HOME'
/root
```

So it is telling you there is no `Downloads` directory in `root`'s home. If you want to run commands as root but in the invoking user's environment, use `sudo -s` instead.

Comment: `sudo -i pwd` might be more explanatory imho

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your command and no joy, however if you do sudo ls -i you will get output.

sudo cd does not work with the -i or not.

What out-put are you looking for from the -i, especially from cd?  cd is just to change directory, and has no real special power, ls does.

From what I read here adding -i to sudo is for when you want to do sudo as another user.  ls -i gives you the index number of each file. per this link:

http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ls1.html